# Is there a converter parameter for bindings in the Backbone.Modelbinding plugin for Backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, knockout.js, model-binding

I recently took over a large Backbone.js project which uses the Backbone.Modelbinding plugin to provide data-binding between models and views, with direct reference to the model attribute names in a "data-bind" attribute in the html elements.

For non-form items, the data-binding is one-way, from the model to the view, but for form items, the user can change the form input so that it updates the model attribute that has been bound to that element, and vice versa -- the model can also update the contents of the form input.

I am in need of some kind of view helper that will display the information in a different format than the data it's bound to in the model, without affecting the model itself.

For instance, if an attribute in the model has a value that is the number 679, I may need the view to display it as $679.00, while having the model's version remain just the number 679.

In other similar libraries, there are easy ways to perform these conversions, in either direction ("converter parameters" in Backbone.Modelbinder, "computed observables" in Knockout.js, I think they're called Converters in Silverlight, etc.). There doesn't appear to be a way to do it using Backbone.Modelbinding, though. Does anyone know of a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the final feature that got half implemented before Backbone.ModelBinding was abandoned. If you can, I would recommend switching to Backbone.ModelBinder.

Comment: That's exactly what I suspected, and pretty much answers my question. Thanks for making the thing in the first place, though. It was an excellent product and is a great inspiration to its successors.

Answer (score 4):

Recommend that you use **backbone.modelbinder**( https://github.com/theironcook/Backbone.ModelBinder ) **+ backbone-nested**( http://afeld.github.com/backbone-nested/ ).Can easily achieve the two-way binding between nested models and views.

There is a demo, I do hope useful for you：
http://files.cnblogs.com/justinw/Nested_Model_bi_Binding.zip

backbone.modelbinder can easily solve your problem,see here:
https://github.com/theironcook/Backbone.ModelBinder#formatting-and-converting-values

Comment: Thanks. I have definitely been considering that, but there are hundreds of html template files, all with numerous data-bind attributes on elements all through them, and I'm not sure I'm ready to take on the project of converting them all to the unobtrusive style of Modelbinder. 

I am going to check out this conversion script, though, tomorrow, to see if it will do the trick:

https://github.com/theironcook/Backbone.ModelBinder/blob/master/sandbox/ConvertDataBindToModelBinder.html

I was just looking for a quick way of making a couple changes to the code I have, if that's an option.

Comment: one possibility would be to bring ModelBinder along side ModelBinding... on the one or two pages that need to be fixed, go ahead and switch. But leave the old ModelBinding code in place for the other pages, until they also need to be changed.